# Recuperar registro en un DATATABLE para poder editarlo - Django

Tags: javascript, python, html5, django, django-forms

Tengo un formulario en cual se registran los siguientes datos:

`ORIGEN`, `CANTIDAD`, `DEFECTO`, `COMPONENTE`, `COMENTARIO` y de un `DATATABLE` se selecciona un `ITEM`. Una vez que se captura la informaciòn se guarda el registro.

La imagen de abajo ejemplifica los campos mencionados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder editar un determinado registro, ya puedo recuperar los siguientes campos:

```
ORIGEN, CANTIDAD, DEFECTO, CANTIDAD, COMPONENTE, COMENTARIO
```

sin embargo desconozco la forma de recuperar el `ITEM` en el `DATATABLE` para seleccionar uno nuevo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Còdigo de la funciòn.

```
def EditarItemValeFgView(request,id_parte):


    editDetalle=DetalleParte.objects.get(parte_id=id_parte)
    piezas=Parte.objects.all() //Se obtiene todas las piezas o ITEMS que se mostraran el DATATABLES

    if request.method=='POST':
        form=DetalleParteForm(request.POST)


        if form.is_valid():
           editDetalle.origen=form.cleaned_data.get('origen') 
           editDetalle.defecto=form.cleaned_data.get('defecto') 
           editDetalle.parte=parte_object                     
           editDetalle.cantidad=form.cleaned_data.get('cantidad') 
           editDetalle.precioUnitarioPieza=parte_object.precioUnitario  
           editDetalle.comentario=form.cleaned_data.get('comentario')  


           editDetalle.subTotal=CalcularSubtotal(p.cantidad,parte_object.precioUnitario)

           editDetalle.save()

    if request.method=='GET':
        form = DetalleParteForm(initial={
            'origen':editDetalle.origen, //Se obtiene el origen
            'defecto':editDetalle.defecto,  //Se obtiene defecto
            'cantidad':editDetalle.cantidad, //Se obtiene la cantidad
            'componente':editDetalle.componente, //Se obtiene componente
            'comentario':editDetalle.comentario}) //Se obtiene comentario

    contex={'form':form,'piezas':piezas}  //Se retorna formulario y pieza
    return render(request,'app/editarpiezafg.html',contex)
```

Còdigo del template.

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
{% load filters %} //Sirve para desplegar las opciones en las listas desplegables
{% block content %}
<br>

<center><h2>Agregar pieza MAC FG</h2></center>
<br/>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="agregar-piezafg-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <label class="col-xs-12 control-label">Origen:</label>

              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                  {{form.origen}}
                <div class="text-danger">{{form.origen.errors}}</div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-2">
                 <label class="col-xs-12 control-label">Defecto:</label>

              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                  {{form.defecto}}
            <div class="text-danger">{{form.defecto.errors}}</div>
              </div>
        </div>
    <br />
      <div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-2">
                 <label class="col-xs-12 control-label">Cantidad:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
                   {{form.cantidad}}
          <div class="text-danger">{{form.cantidad.errors}}</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <label class="col-xs-12 control-label">Componente:</label>

          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
                      {{form.componente}}
           <div class="text-danger">{{form.componente.errors}}</div>
          </div>
       </div>
        <br />
       <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-2">

              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-4">

                   <br />
                   <br />
                   <div class="alert alert-success"  role="alert">
                        Último registro<br />
                     -------------------------<br />
                     NP: {{utm}} <br />
                     Cantidad: {{utm.cantidad}}<br/>
                     Origen:{{utm.origen|origenFilter}}<br/>
                     Defecto: {{utm.defecto|defectosValeFgFilter}}
                   </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <label class="col-xs-12 control-label">Comentario:</label>            
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-4">
                  {{form.comentario}}  
             <div class="text-danger">{{form.comentario.errors}}</div> 
             </div>
             <br/>
        </div>

    </div>
    <br/>


<div class="container">


        <br>
        <br>
        {% if piezas %}

            <table id="datatables" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

             <thead>

                  <tr>
                    <th>Seleccionar</th>
                    <th>Unidad Negocio</th>
                    <th>Proyecto</th>
                    <th>Numero de parte</th>
                    <th>Modelo</th>
                    <th>$ Unitario</th>                   
                    <th>Nivel</th>

                  </tr>

             </thead>

            <tbody>
      {% for item in piezas %}
                <tr>

                    //Sirve para activar el boton guardar, siempre y cuando se haya seleccionado un radio buttom
                    <td>
                       <label class="btn btn-success active">
                        <input autocomplete="off" name="checked_parte" type="radio" id="checked_parte" value="{{item.id}}" onChange="comprobar(this);"/>
                        </label>

                    </td>

                    <td>{{item.unidadNegocio}}<br></td>
                    <td>{{item.proyecto}}<br></td>
                    <td>{{item.numeroParte}}<br></td>

                    <td>{{item.modelo}}<br></td>
                    <td>${{item.precioUnitario}}<br></td>
                    <td>{{item.nivel}}<br></td>

                </tr>
      {% endfor %}
        {% else %}


        {% endif %}
                </tbody>

            </table>
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-9">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button name="boton" type="submit" id="boton" class="btn btn-success" disabled>Guardar</button>

            <a href="/finPieza/{{v}}/"  class="btn btn-danger">Finalizar</a> //Este botòn sirve para calcular el subtotal y total de cada una de las piezas seleccionadas

        </div>
        <br>
        <br>

    </div>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Deberias de incluir tu codigo

Comment: Editado, gracias!!

Comment: Necesitas chequear si `item.id` es igual a `form.id`, y si lo es, agregas la propiedad `checked`